# Oracleasm deletedisk failed Unable to clear disk

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rac, oracle-asm

I have dropped the disk from ASM diskgroup:

```
> ALTER DISKGROUP DATA01 DROP DISK DISK1;
```

Oracle did a rebalance operation and then dropped the disk.

Now, I want to delete the disk from ASM library and return the disk to the system:

```
# oracleasm deletedisk -v DISK1
  Clearing disk header: oracleasm-write-label: Unable to open device "/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK1": 
  Device or resource busy failed
  Unable to clear disk "DISK1"
```

The system details:
11.2.0.1 2-node RAC

**Why does ASM not clearing the disk header? Where to see the detailed log?**

**------------------------------------Edit1--------------------------------------------**

```
# fuser /dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK1
```

returns nothing on both nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I checked that there were no extents on DISK1.

```
$ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [+ASM1] ?

SQL> select PXN_KFFXP,  -- physical extent number
           XNUM_KFFXP, -- virtual extent number
           DISK_KFFXP, -- disk number
           AU_KFFXP    -- allocation unit number
    from X$KFFXP
    where DISK_KFFXP=1;

no rows selected
```

I cleared the disk header by dd:

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/oracleasm/disks/DISK1 bs=1024 count=100
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
102400 bytes (102 kB) copied, 0.000156 seconds, 656 MB/s
```

**Note**: My allocation unit is 1MB that is why I am using bs=1024.

Then deleted disk by oracleasm:

```
# oracleasm deletedisk DISK1
# oracleasm scandisks    <--Do this step on all nodes
```

To tell the truth it is not a good way to solve the problem, because when I run the following command on the second node:

```
/sbin/blkid | grep oracleasm

/dev/sdg1: LABEL="DISK6" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="DISK1" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdh2: LABEL="DISK8" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdh3: LABEL="DISK9" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdh4: LABEL="DISK10" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdh1: LABEL="DISK7" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdi1: LABEL="DISK11" TYPE="oracleasm"
/dev/sdi2: LABEL="DISK12" TYPE="oracleasm"
```

It shows me the label DISK1.

So clearing the ASM disk header using dd left some junks.

Comment: I'd be tempted to ask Oracle support about this - could cause trouble down the line

Comment: I think I had similar issue. Oracle support suggested to reboot the server. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the header is not a clean way.

The good way is to run as root:

```
oracleasm deletedisk -v <label>
```

Disk `<label>` defines an unmarked device.
Dropping disk: done

And repeat on each cluster node, if so.

Answer (score -2):

I solved it by logging off from ASM and changing directory away from /dev/oracleasm/disks. Afterwards it worked ok.

Comment: This answer is *very* unclear as to what you did.